# Webpack 3 cannot resolve assets from SASS file

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

Im facing issue only with images and fonts when loading from a SASS file.
Everything else is loading, and getting populated at **./public** folder except for images and fonts.

**ERROR**:

`Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/fonts/ProximaNovaA-Bold.eot' in '/Users/ajinkyaborade/projects/product/src/sass'`

package.json ...

```
"webpack": "^3.12.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
```

...

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: './style.css'
});

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    context: SRC,
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/assets'),
        stats: 'errors-only',
        open: true,
        port: 8080,
        compress: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public']),
        extractPlugin
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                // include: SRC,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: './assets/',
                        limit: 8192
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
                // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: extractPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: 1
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    fallback: 'style-loader'
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env', 'stage-0', 'react']
                    }
                }
            }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.scss']
    }
};
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a main.scss file, where you import all your scss files? Then you should use the [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader/).
The resolve-url-loader sits between sass-loader and css-loader. Please make sure, that all loaders **before** resolve-url-loader have prop sourceMap set to true. Even for production!

```
 {
                test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
                // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: extractPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
                        }
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: 1
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    fallback: 'style-loader'
                })
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried your suggestions, but the error persists with new error for 'resolve-url-loader' https://i.imgur.com/ZmuTlu2.png

Comment: i fixed by moving `@font-'s` to a css files and import that into react.